# Securing application in Silverlight

Tags: security, silverlight-5.0

I have this application in silverlight 5. Actually the problem is with its security. I'd used HTTPS but still the query I fire within the application can be decrypted by FIDDLER and can be used to get all the data from the database. Please suggest something to prevent this. Or at least any link to get start with. I'd already implemented some suggestions from MSDN but still the application has the same issue.

Comment: It can be decrypted by Fiddler as you have configured a certificate on Fiddler and either trusted it or added it as an exception in the browser. A normal end user will not have done this so their traffic should be encrypted between SL and your server if it is HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks, but still there are users who would have done that. Isn't their any way to protect the data that transmitted via server to client in secure form? Even SSL didn't work.

Comment: If a user trusts a certificate they shouldn't, then you can no longer protect them. Why would your users be trusting certificates issued by a web debugging proxy?